# Converting String to Int32 Trouble

Tags: c#, tryparse, int32

I'm having trouble converting an `string` to `Int32` when calling it. This is what I'm struggling with.

```
public static int GetProgramLength()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter program length:");
    return Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine);
}
```

Its telling me,

> No overload for method, "Try Parse" takes 1 argument.

Comment: I already fixed the () after the readline, I just forgot to put it on here.

Comment: [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> You need to specify the out value to use `Int32.TryParse()` the result
>   of `TryParse` is stored to the out parameter(`outParam` will be `0` if it failed to convert the input string),and also it will return
>   a boolean value to indicate whether the conversion is success or a
>   failure;

So you have to correct your code as like the following:

```
int outParam=0;
Console.WriteLine("Please enter program length:");
Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out outParam);
return outParam;
```

Comment: Or, since the result of the Try is not being checked, just use `.Parse()`